# Timestamp on Spring roo

Tags: spring, timestamp, spring-roo

I added the add on for time stamp on spring roo to a particular entity. The time stamp works fine, that is to say, when listing all entries in an entity the date created and updated fields are visible. The issue is, when I view the entries web page I can also see the time stamp of other entries to the left hand side, how do you remove this, I have looked into the show.jspx files but it's quite trivail[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like project/suffix are entities themselves.
By default spring roo use application conversion service to convert these objects to strings.

In your project, look for ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean, and push in the methods you need to change.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Indeed project/suffix are entities, but document record is an entity that is dependent on both of them thus a user chooses the necessary categories first and creates a doc record.Could you please give a sample method ? thanks @solubris